# How to read the return value from a function?

Tags: c++, winapi

In C++ I'm trying to use the function `GetActiveWindow()` to get the handle of the current window but I don't know how I obtain the functions return value.

Comment: HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows the prototype as:

```
HWND WINAPI GetActiveWindow(void);
```

this means you can call it just like so:

```
const HWND active_window = GetActiveWindow();
```

this puts the handle in the `active_window` variable, and you can use it directly, i.e. send it to other functions that expect a `HWND` window handle.

As pointed out in a comment, you can also use [C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EzywvCM9/)'s `auto` feature to figure out the type:

```
const auto active_window = GetActiveWindow();
```

Again, this is a [C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EzywvCM9/) feature, but assuming you're on Visual Studio it should be fine.

Comment: Pwnt, because I have `auto` and you do not.

Comment: thanks! Your response was the easiest to understand & implement.

Answer (score 1):

The same as for any other function- you create an object of that type and construct it from the function call.

```
auto x = GetActiveWindow();
```